# Why can't I create an image and set it as the background in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

So, this is what I am trying:

```
    import cv2
    import cv2.cv as cv
    cv2.namedWindow(threeDWinName, cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    img2 = cv.CreateImage((320, 240), 32, 1)
    cv2.imshow(threeDWinName,img2)
```

Does anybody know what is going wrong with this?  I get `TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more recent version of OpenCV, `cv2` uses numpy arrays for images, the preceding version `cv` used opencv's special Mat's. In your code you've created an image as a `Mat` using the old `cv` function `CreateImage`, and then tried to view it using the newer `cv2.imshow` function, but `cv2.imshow` expects a numpy array...

...so all you need to do is import numpy, and then change you `CreateImage` line to:

```
img2 = np.zeros((320,240),np.float32)
```

And then it should be fine :)

Comment: what library do I need to import then, other than cv2 and cv?

Comment: @Sam Heather - hey, you also need to `import numpy as np`, [Numpy](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List_With_Doc) is a powerful numerical/ mathamatics library, its really great.

Comment: Is there an alternative to using a numpy array?  Why can't I just render a blank background as createImg object?

Comment: @Sam Heather - Yes, you can avoid `Numpy` by using only the old `cv`, so in your code keep `cv.CreateImage`, and use `cv.ShowImage('threeDWinName',img2);cv.WaitKey(0)` instead of `imshow`. Also was there a particular reason to unaccept my answer?

Comment: Ok thanks.  I unaccepted it because I couldn't get it to work so thought it wrong.  Undone now.